# How to initialize MoPub?

Tags: android, mopub

I'm pretty new in Mopub. Just trying to add Mopub ads in Android. So, I've been following this documentation: 
https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/initialize/

The documentation suggests to write something like this:

```
MoPub.initializeSdk(context, new SdkConfiguration.Builder("AD_UNIT_ID")
                .build(), null);
```

But I its not clear, which `AD_UNIT_ID` to write in the code? Banner, Interstitial or Reward ad unit ID?
or do I have to initialize each time before showing any kinds of ads?

Comment: You can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64470546/6319209

Comment: You can set any AD_UNIT_ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MoPub integration document:

You only need to initialize once using **any valid ad unit ID from your app**. Ad requests should only be made once the SDK initialization has completed.

It means you can init MoPub SDK with your interstitial or reward ad unit id, etc.