# MoPub initialization with SdkInitializationListener

Tags: mopub

I like to initialize MoPub SDK in Android and continue loading banners and interstitials only if SDK init is complete and successful.

What can be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

create a variable listner :

```
private SdkInitializationListener Listner2;
```

then put this code inside your oncreate :

```
    final SdkConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e");
    configBuilder.withLogLevel(DEBUG);
    Listner2 = new SdkInitializationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFinished() {
            Log.d("MoPub", "SDK initialized");
            mInterstitial.load();
        }
    };
    MoPub.initializeSdk(this, configBuilder.build(), Listner2);
```

The code above load test interstitial if SDK init is complete and successful.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to accomplish with Android's new Livedata objects. There objects are observable and you can receive their changes wherever you want in your app.

Technology and patterns used:

- Livedata
- Singleton pattern
- MoPub SDK 5.11.1

I will show you how by code snippets

**Singleton pattern**

```
public class MoPubSdk {

    private static MoPubSdk INSTANCE;

    public static MoPubSdk getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if(MoPubSdk.INSTANCE == null) {
            MoPubSdk.INSTANCE = new MoPubSdk(activity);
        }
        return MoPubSdk.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

**Constructor with SdkInitializationListener function**

Note the MutableLiveData object that changes it's value to true (isInitialized) when the listener is called and the MoPub SDK is ready to call ads. Also see the showConsentIfNeeded function which you can see in the next code block. Just comment the function if not needed.

```
public class MoPubSdk {

    private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> isMoPubSdkInitialized = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private Activity mActivity;

    private MoPubSdk(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;

        SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("ANYadunitID")
                .withLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? MoPubLog.LogLevel.DEBUG : MoPubLog.LogLevel.NONE)
                .build();

        MoPub.initializeSdk(activity, sdkConfiguration, initSdkListener());
    }

    private SdkInitializationListener initSdkListener() {
        return new SdkInitializationListener() {
           @Override
           public void onInitializationFinished() {
           /* MoPub SDK initialized.
           Check if you should show the consent dialog here, and make your ad requests. */
                Log.d("MoPub", "SDK initialized");
                isMoPubSdkInitialized.setValue(true);
                showConsentIfNeeded();
            }
        };
    }  

    public LiveData<Boolean> isMoPubSdkInitialized() {
        return isMoPubSdkInitialized;
    }
}
```

**Optional consent Dialog**

```
private void showConsentIfNeeded() {
    PersonalInfoManager mPersonalInfoManager = MoPub.getPersonalInformationManager();

    Log.d("customeee", "Can collect pers information? "+MoPub.canCollectPersonalInformation()
            + ".\nShould show consent dialog? "+mPersonalInfoManager.shouldShowConsentDialog());

    if(!MoPub.canCollectPersonalInformation()) {
            if(mPersonalInfoManager.shouldShowConsentDialog()) {
            mPersonalInfoManager.loadConsentDialog(new ConsentDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentDialogLoaded() {
                    mPersonalInfoManager.showConsentDialog();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentDialogLoadFailed(@NonNull MoPubErrorCode moPubErrorCode) {
                    MoPubLog.i("Consent dialog failed to load.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So much for initialization. Now let's call the MoPub SDK from an activity and continue with banner loading.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private MoPubSdk moPubSdk;

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    moPubSdk = MoPubSdk.getInstance(this);
    moPubSdk.isMoPubSdkInitialized().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
            if (aBoolean)
                //Init your banner here.
        }
    });
    }
}
```

The LiveData is easy to explain. First time the MoPub SDK initialization begins the Livedata object is false. It takes some time to init, on success the value switches to true and the observer gets called, you can begin banner loading.

On switching activities during init or call MoPubSdk#getInstance another time, the value is already true and gets passed directly on #observe call and you init your banner straight away.